# 500 internal server error with spark servlet

Tags: neo4j, embedded-jetty, spark-java

The issue I am having is that when I send the post request , the data are added to the data base , but the response I have is internal server error . When I check the database everything is added , but the error is still showing up after the execution. 
Using spark above neo4j database .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It came out that the most recent version of Spark(2.5.4), the one I'm was using at the time of the above issue was not showing me the error event with SLF4J(1.7.7), I finally switched back to spark version 2.0.0, and I figured out that the neo4j was sending an error with clearer details. Those details helped me to fix my problem.